# Jquery plugin hovercard not work in dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery plugin Hovercard works well in simple HTML code but does not work when i used it in javascript code (dynamically creating html code through javascript). Maybe this is also a general problem, how can jquery plugin work in js code generated content?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any of your code so I can't be sure that this will help. But the issue with adding HTML dynamically with JS is that the resulting DOM elements would not have the necessary event handlers attached to them (in the case of Hovercard, `mouseover`, `mouseout` and probably others). The solution would be to call `$(...).hovercard({...})` on the newly added DOM elements *after* you add them. e.g.

```
$("body").append("<a class='hovercard'>New element.</a>");
$("body a.hovercard").hovercard({...});
```

After this block, the `a` tag would have the Hovercard effect. If you call `hovercard()` on some elements in `$(document).ready()`, then *only* those elements which are present when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires will have the effect (not any elements you add later).

Comment: I am using InfiniteScroll plugin. In first page hovercard works as it is expected. But after adding other dynamic content, it doesnot work. Do I need to call hovercard function after each addition of dynamic content?